# How to send mail related to a category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have 3 models Quotes, Categories, and Subscribers.

Essentially, it's a newsletter application. Subscribers can select a category and then enter their email and they will receive quotes related to that category via email.

There's two issues here,

```
1. The category's are stored in a constant in the category model. 
so how do I display the category type that the subscriber chose
in text format? I'd like to show in the email
something like "here's your email on <%= category.name %>" which would translate to
"here's your email on Food." 

2. I'd like to ONLY send emails about the category that the subscriber subscribed to. 
How might I accomplish this? Please provide examples.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Category.rb

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quote
  belongs_to :subscriber

  CATEGORY_TYPE = {
    1 => "Food",
    2 => "Fitness",
    3 => 'Cats',
  }

end
```

Quote.rb

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  belongs_to :category

  validates :title, presence: true

end

Subscriber.rb

class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category

  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "quote_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "subscriber_id"
    t.integer  "category_type"
  end

  create_table "quotes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "subscribers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**Update subscribers_mailer.rb**

```
  def SendMyEmail(email, category, quote, subscribers)
    @category = category
    @quote = quote
    @subscribers = subscribers
    @email = email

    mail to: email, subject: 'New Quotes'
   end
  end
```

and then of course:

```
Category.all.each do |category|
    SubscriptionMailer.SendMyEmail("email@test.com", category, category.quotes.first, category.subscribers).deliver
end
```

**Update:**

```
There's two remaining issues here, 

    1. Categories aren't syncing to subscribers. For example when I run category.subscribers.last 
    it's nil. and category.subscribers throws an empty array. How can I sync these? I think it has
    to do with the fact that subscribers are selecting a category from the Category::CATEGORY_TYPES
    constant as seen in the view code below.

    2. I'd like to automate it so that these emails are sent to subscribers once a day. 
    How might I do this? 


view code (subscribers/new.html.erb:

    <div class="styled email-input2">
        <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
        <% if @subscriber.errors.any? %>
          <div class="errorExplanation" style="color: white;">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@subscriber.errors.count, 'error') %> encountered:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @subscriber.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>
          <li><%= m %></li>
         <% end %>
         </ul>
         </div>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.fields_for :subscriber, @subscriber.build_category do |cat| %>
      <%= cat.select(:category_type, Category::CATEGORY_TYPE.map{|p| [p[1], p[0]]}, {prompt: 'Please select'}, {class: 'styled email-input2'}) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you storing the CATEGORY_TYPE value in the model as well?

Comment: Yes, but as an integer, updated the post with the schema

Comment: can you add your other schema's as well. I think you intended the relations a little differently.

Comment: Ok it is a bit odd so let me make sure I understand:

Each category can have 1 and only 1 subscriber. Is that what you wanted?

Each category can have 1 and only 1 quote. Is that what you wanted?

A more common design for this would be to have MANY subscribers for each category and MANY quotes for each category.

Comment: Ah you're right, can you provide some examples of the proper associations, how to actually display the name of the category from the constant? And how to send only quotes related to the category that the subscriber has subscribed to? The mailer is setup and running as well as the frontend just having some issues with the backend. Almost there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first lets modify the migrations:

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
#DELETE QUOTE_ID AND SUBSCRIBER ID
t.string   "name"    
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "category_type"
end

create_table "quotes", force: true do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "body"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.references :category  #this will add integer category_id

end

create_table "subscribers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.references :category   #this will add integer category_id

end
```

Next we will modify the models to reflet the changes in the migration:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quotes
    has_many :subscribers

    CATEGORY_TYPE = {
    1 => "Food",
    2 => "Fitness",
    3 => 'Cats',
    }

end


class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    validates :title, presence: true

end


class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category

    validates :email, presence: true
end
```

Now you can get the subscribers for a cateogyr using the following:

category = Category.find(1) #use whatever id you want
category.subscribers #list of all subscribers for a category

Getting the quotes for a category is similarly straight forward:

```
category = Category.find(1)
category.quotes
```

So assuming your mailer takes a category, quote and a list of subscribers for the email to send

```
Category.all.each do |category|
    Mailer.SendMyEmail(category, category.quotes.first, category.subscribers).deliver
end
```

In the "SendMyEmail" function in your mailer you will have

```
def SendMyEmail(category, quote, subscribers)
    #YOUR CODE FOR TYHE VIEW HERE
end
```

Comment: Awesome! This was one of the best answers to date. Question though, where would the Category.all.each do code go? I'm guessing in the controller? Also, how do I ensure that I'm only sending quotes associated with the category they selected and not quotes for ALL categories?

Comment: Lets tackle these one at a time.
How do I ensure that I'm only sending quotes associated with the category:

Quotes now belong to a category. The change to the schema makes it so a quote can only belong to one category. So it should no longer be an issue.

The category all

Wherever you are triggering the email from. If you are going to have a lot of categories you should kick this to background using delayed jobs, or resque. But that is probably for another day.

Comment: Updated the original post with view code. It may be helpful

Comment: Thanks huge help!! ALthough, It doesn't seem to be storing the subscribers, For example when I run category.subscribers.last it's nil. and category.subscribers throws an empty array. I think this has to do with the fact that we're using the CATEGORY_TYPES constant.. how can we get this to work? it's the last major thing.